# Trait and group membership (successful people take risks)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A person can belong or not to a group, where group membership entails event G. Members of this group have a trait (entailed by event T) more frequently than those outside the group, such that $P(T|G) > P(T|\bar{G})$.

We observe two individuals, one with the trait, one without. Can we be confident that the individual with the trait is more likely to belong to the group?

Equivalently, prove that if $P(T|G) > P(T|\bar{G})$, then $P(G|T) > P(G|\bar{T})$.

We only know that $0 < P(T) < 1$ and $0 < P(G) < 1$.

*Motivation: A friend mentioned the saying that successful people take risks. We are wondering IF it is indeed that case that successful people take more risk than the "unsuccessful", should one take risks to be successful*

**UPDATE:**

I ran a quick [simulation](https://gist.github.com/alexandres/ee6065f59d16d2095156327e32c4b81c) and the implication holds.

Answer (score 0):

$P(T) = P(T|G)P(G) + P(T|\bar G)P(\bar G)$

Since $P(T|G) > P(T|\bar G)$,

$
P(T) < P(T|G)P(G) + P(T|G)P(\bar G) \\
P(T) < P(T|G)(P(G) + P(\bar G)) \\
P(T) < P(T|G)
$

Thus

$
P(T|G) - P(T|G)P(T) > P(T) - P(T|G)P(T) \\
P(T|G)(1 - P(T)) > P(T)(1 - P(T|G)) \\
P(G)P(T|G)(1 - P(T)) > P(G)P(T)(1 - P(T|G)) \\
P(G)P(T|G)/P(T) > P(G)(1 - P(T|G))/(1 - P(T)) \\
P(G)P(T|G)/P(T) > P(G)(1 - P(T|G))/P(\bar T) \\
P(G|T) > P(G)P(\bar T|G)/P(\bar T) \\
P(G|T) > P(G|\bar T) \\
$

Therefore, $P(T|G) > P(T|\bar G) \Rightarrow P(G|T) > P(G|\bar T)$.

Q.E.D.

*thanks to [Marcus Ritt](https://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~mrpritt/doku.php) for the proof*

I think this is all correct. Interesting little theorem. If you have seen this in any book or paper, please post in the comments. I would be very interested to know where it comes up and if it has a name.